# route new controller - codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have situation when I want to create other controller.

my steps:

I create controller controller/Form.php

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('apanel/login');
                }
                else
                {
                        $this->load->view('apanel/index');
                }
        }
}
```

Then I create views/apanel/login.php, views/apanel/index.php

now I want to acces my login page but can not http://example.com/codeigniter/apanel/
http://example.com/codeigniter/apanel/login.php
http://example.com/codeigniter/apanel/index.php

but 404 error not found.

I have devault

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

but this is for other view.

how to create new view for this login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access login page like that --

http://example.com/codeigniter/apanel/

then please follow this pattern --

```
$route['string_which_you_want_to_show_in_url'] = 'controller/method';

$route['apanel'] = 'form/index';
```

using that you will access from left routing parameter